# webpack compiled number to hash string in json file which has many float number

Tags: webpack

source file: json type,  some content:

```
[118.23901574108356,32.92370127999007],[118.29968387321216,32.77740530001451],[118.39910932763334,32.73089651146488],[118.72017500167505,32.73213674581416],[118.74823530461566,32.83853852013658],[118.79774132670087,32.86507436788773],[118.85737593005518,32.97230296540948],[118.99297488798058,32.96204519293134],
```

after build: js file , the chunk content:

```
[118.23901574108356,32.92370127999007],[118.29968387321216,32.777c9db9001451],[118.39910932763334,32.73089651146488],[118.72017500167505,32.73213674581416],[118.74823530461566,32.83853852013658],[118.79774132670087,32.86507436788773],[118.85737593005518,32.97230296540948],[118.99297488798058,32.96204519293134],
```

we can see the content '32.77740530001451' transfer to '32.777c9db9001451'.

and the web page collapse with error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 75628
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.16954 (geojson-eab57d6e.c3fd52b3ff86.js:formatted:4)
    at r (main-9b24bb21.bundle.js:1)
```

**Other relevant information:**
webpack version:  5.40.x
Node.js version: 12.14.1
Operating System: Mac OS

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CrossoriginWebpackPlugin = require('./crossoriginWebpackPlugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

const envKeyMap = {
  REACT: true,
  PUBLIC: true,
  GENERATE_SOURCEMAP: true,
};

// 构造注入到项目的全局变量
const envConfig = {};
const { env } = process;
for (const k in env) {
  for (const _reservedkey in envKeyMap) {
    if (k.startsWith(_reservedkey)) {
      envConfig[k] = JSON.stringify(env[k]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'production',
  stats: 'normal',
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[fullhash:8].bundle.js',
    publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_URL_ROOT,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:12].js',
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          'ts-loader',
        ],
        include: path.resolve('src'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.resolve('src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { modules: true },
              },
              'sass-loader',
            ],
          },
          {
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 4096,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@src': path.resolve('./src'),
    },
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash:5].css',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: './src/public/favicon.ico', to: './' },
        { from: './src/public/logo192.png', to: './' },
        { from: './src/public/logo512.png', to: './' },
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/public/index.html',
      publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_URL_ROOT,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': envConfig,
    }),
    new CrossoriginWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    splitChunks: {
      maxSize: 2000000,
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          type: 'css/mini-extract',
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
          priority: 100,
        },
        geojson: {
          test: /[\\/]src\/constant\/china-geojson[\\/]/,
          name: 'geojson',
          maxSize: 2000000,
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          priority: 40,
        },
        tencent: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules\/@tencent[\\/]/,
          name: 'tencent',
          minChunks: 1,
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: 30,
        },
        node_modules: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'node_modules',
          minChunks: 1,
          chunks: 'all',
          priority: 20,
        },
        // common: {
        //   name: 'common',
        //   chunks: 'all',
        //   minChunks: 1, // 模块被引用1次以上的才抽离
        //   priority: 10,
        // },
      },
    },
    minimizer: [
      new TerserWebpackPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        exclude: /\/node_modules/,
        extractComments: false,
        terserOptions: {
          warnings: false,
          compress: {
            unused: true,
            drop_debugger: true, // 删除debugger
            drop_console: true, // 删除console
            inline: 2,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};

if (process.env.ANALYZER) {
  config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

here is the build file in cdn :
https://uma-saas-asset-qa-1302115263.file.myqcloud.com/uma-front-assets-main/qa/20210903143651/geojson-eab57d6e.c3fd52b3ff86.js

you can serch c9 in the file ,and you can find Some similar cases 。

These cases are not necessarily present. The error hash that appears on different machines is different, or it does not appear on some machines. Changes in source content will also affect the content of these wrong hashes。

Answer (score 0):

- transform long number to string （alternative plan）
- replace terserPlugin to others plugin like uglifyJSPlugin (if using terserPlugin to optimize)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).